# How to compare a column against every other column in a SQL query with a wide table?

Tags: sql, correlation, presto, amazon-athena, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to implement a query in AWS Athena where I compute the Pearson Correlation coefficient of a selected column against every other column in a matrix, and return a sorted list.

The data is stored in S3 as a CSV file and looks like this:

```
col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 .... col_15000
  0    124    56   200  ....   4
  0     0     44    0   ....   0
....
```

I want to be able to calculate corr(col_1, col_2), corr(col_1, col_3), ...cor(col_1, col_15000) and sort the results by the correlation coefficients (find the most/least correlated columns).

What is the most efficient way to write this query? I would like this query to be as performant as possible. The obvious answer is to generate a query like this:

```
SELECT
corr(col_1, col_2) AS cor_2,
corr(col_1, col_3) AS cor_3,
...

corr(col_1, col_15000) AS cor_15000
```

However, this seems tedious, and the query size limit is quickly reached. Is there a better way that doesn't sacrifice (or increases) performance? This can easily be parallelized, as each individual correlation coefficient can be computed independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not the answer you probably are looking for but this is does not seem like something that should be done via Athena/SQL/Presto.  The needing thousands of custom columns is a big red flag.

This sounds more like a job for a [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) Job which could be run in [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/) via an [ETL Job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job.html).

Since your data is already in Athena, it should already be cataloged in Glue and you can use a [GlueContext](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html) in spark to load your data frame directly from that datasource.

Spark jobs can be done in Python (via pyspark) or Scala.  Creating these coefficient columns via a code loop and then writing them out to another file shouldn't be a very complicated script.

Assuming you are unfamiliar with most of this, it may be good to go through this example/tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One issue here is that we need this for a web application. I was initially worried about the latency issue with Spark. This isn't a one-time query - we would have to persist it in memory to have it readily available. I'm not quite sure if that's possible with Spark and Glue.

Comment: Is the data in single csv or many csv?  Can this type of thing just be pre-processsed when the file(s) hit S3 so you don’t need to calculate it in on the fly?  Or does the web client provide the csv to analyzed?

Comment: Pre-processing isn't an option here, as users can request correlations on any subsets of rows, and there are other operations we would like to perform. We need a live compute solution.